# Как отследить кол-во строк и столбцов в двух таблицах и добавить недостающее количество в третью таблицу?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Необходимо что бы при нажатии на кнопку умножения происходил расчет кол-ва строк матрицы для матрицы "С". Сам расчет: Кол-во строк матрицы  С равны кол-ву строк матрицы А и кол-во столбцов С равны кол-во столбцов В и если в матрице С не хватает  строк или столбцов то добавить их.Как реализовать данную схему?
Рабочий пример данных манипуляций для матрицы С [здесь](http://www.bl2.ru/matematic/matrix/mult.html)

с 56 по 78 строку идет условие на проверку строк и столбцов.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGPEde

```
var matA_str = $('.matrix_a');

var matB_str = $('.matrix_b');

function error(){
    if(matA_str.find('tr:first td').length != matB_str.find('tr').length){
        $('.left-side').addClass('error strError');
    }
    else{
        $('.left-side').removeClass('error');
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39905/discussion-on-question-by-drop----------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#btnCheckResultSize").click(function() {
    var needRows = $('.matrix_a').find('tr').length;
    var needCols = $('.matrix_b').find('tr:first td').length;
    
    var hasRows = $('.matrix_c').find('tr').length;
    var hasCols = $('.matrix_c').find('tr:first td').length;
    
    var message = "Info:\n";
    
    if (needRows > hasRows)
      message += "\n- add " + (needRows - hasRows) + " row[s]";
    else if (needRows < hasRows)
      message += "\n- remove " + (hasRows - needRows) + " row[s]";
    else
      message += "\n- rows match";
    
    message += "\n";
    
    if (needCols > hasCols)
      message += "\n- add " + (needCols - hasCols) + " column[s]";
    else if (needCols < hasCols)
      message += "\n- remove " + (hasCols - needCols) + " column[s]";
    else
      message += "\n- columns match";
    
    alert(message);
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
div {
  display:inline-block;
}

td {
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="matrix_a">
<table cellspacing="1" cellpaddin="1" border="1">
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
x
<div class="matrix_b">
<table cellspacing="1" cellpaddin="1" border="1">
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
=
<div class="matrix_c">
<table cellspacing="1" cellpaddin="1" border="1">
  <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<br />
<button type="button" id="btnCheckResultSize">Check Result Size</button>
```

Comment: Гораздо меньшей кровью можно было обойтись если кидать столбцы или строки при добавлении данных вещей в матрицы)
Не особо пока еще понял код,но судя по всему вместо alert писать уже функцию клонирования и вставки а так же вкидывать функцию плейсхолдера?

Comment: Мне как раз подсказали почему это плохо _"Мне кажется, что так делать не стоит, так как нельзя дописывать в финальную матрицу строки/столбцы, если A нельзя умножить на B, просто смысла нет."_

Comment: @Drop - "вместо alert писать уже функцию клонирования и вставки" - да, или удаления.

Comment: @Drop `if (нельзя перемножить) { alert("нельзя перемножить!"); return; }`

Comment: Не могу понять какое условие закидывать в if,если выводиться такой то message , то используем  добавить  или удалить строки,столбцы?

Comment: Как по синтаксису будет копировать элемент столько то раз?
`$('.matrix_c').find('tr td:last').clone`
и нужное кол-во раз копирования брать тут
`(needRows - hasRows)`

Comment: Если я не ошибся то кол-во недостающих  элементов берется именно здесь `(needRows - hasRows)` ?

Comment: Что-то не могу понять,вот есть у меня цикл который копирует элемент определённое кол-во раз а как забирать значения из `(needRows - hasRows)` и вставлять его в условия?

Comment: @Drop - прошу прощения, не понял, какие значения и какие условия - объясните, пожалуйста, подробнее.